# Cell-centered DG extension to the two-point flux approximation scheme

Tags: finite-element, finite-volume, discontinuous-galerkin

A current problem that I am working on requires me to compute the solution from the heat diffusion evolution on a discontinuous function. More precisely - I have a Delaunay triangulation and within each triangle a polynomial function is defined such that it can be discontinuous at the edges. For a constant function within each triangle the two-point flux approximation scheme is applicable (precisely because I have a Delaunay triangulation).

Is there a DG extension/analogue to such a cell-centered scheme? I would like to be able to use a similar cell-centered scheme on cells with higher polynomial degrees.

To put it simply, I am looking for a (simpler) method to perform homogeneous diffusion on a mesh where discontinuous polynomial functions are defined within each cell (preferably one that extends to higher degree polynomials unlike the FVM scheme that I mentioned).

Comment: There is a vast literature on DG methods for diffusion pde. E.g., (1)  https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898717440 (mostly about interior penalty methods) (2) DOI:10.1007/978-3-319-19267-3 (3) DOI:10.1007/978-3-642-22980-0

Comment: @cfdlab Great book! Thank you for recommending it.